# How to change the component id on the data table

Tags: javascript, css, xpages, lotus-domino, xpages-ssjs

How to change the component id on the data table ?? Repeat works!! Data Table does not change the id?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xp:view xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core">

<xp:repeat id="rAnal" rows="30" style="width:auto" indexVar="rIndx" repeatControls="true" first="0" value="#{java script:return 5;}">
            <xp:inputText id="iAnal_${rIndx}"></xp:inputText>
            <xp:br></xp:br>
        </xp:repeat>
    <xp:br></xp:br>
    <xp:br></xp:br>

    <xp:dataTable id="dataTable1" rows="30" indexVar="tIndx" first="0" value="#{java script:return 5;}">
        <xp:column id="column1">
            <xp:inputText id="input_${tIndx}"></xp:inputText></xp:column>

    </xp:dataTable></xp:view>
```

Comment: The question seem a bit odd, what have you tried and what happend?
use the source pane and type the new id

Comment: Do you use the generated ids in SSJS or CSJS? What do you want to achieve with the ids? Is e.g. setting a class `styleClass="#{javascript:'dataTableInput_' + tIndx}"` and using it in CSJS with `dojo.query(".dataTableInput_0")` an option?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do that with the dataTable component.

You have to declare `id` attribute for component before everything else. Also, it cannot be modified in the runtime. Repeat has `repeatControls="true"` attribute which creates controls inside the repeat iterator once and reuse them for all subsequent updates. Therefore it can provide value bindings  for `id` attribute. However, dataTable component has no such an ability.